# Mysql: How do I find all the users with ALTER permissions or any permissions?

Tags: mysql

I have lot of users in `mysql` db. How do I **filter users** based on a certain permission?

Like I need to *find all users* that have `CREATE` or `ALTER` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql stores use privileges in the schema named `mysql`.

If you want to select users who have those privileges at global or database level,
the query you are looking for is:

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE Alter_priv = 1 OR Create_priv = 1
UNION
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.db WHERE Alter_priv = 1 OR Create_priv = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL store all the privileges in `mysql` schema and there are various tables based on what kind of privileges you would want to look for. Below are tables in which different privileges are stored.

- tables_priv
- columnss_priv
- procs_priv

You can have a look at what privileges you can find in each of these tables over [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant-tables.html)